# How to make Visual Studio Intellisense recommend "" Include?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense

In VS2019, when I have the possibility to include a class, Intellisense only suggests includes with angled brackets (<>). But in most cases I want quote includes ("").
Is there a way to customize it/ let Intellisense suggest both?

[image]

Comment: Did this header files write by yourself on your project or you use nuget package? Did you add these header files into `Include Directories`? As far as I know, if you config it into include directories, it will recommend to use `<>`first. And if the header files are under your project, it will recommend to use `" "`first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually**, VS does not have such option to automatically switch to realize your requirements. I think this behavior depends on how you reference the header file into the project.  So you have to change the way which you import these header files.

**Note**: `<>` searches the header files under [include directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019) or [additional include directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019)

while `""` searches the header files under your project folder first and then search under `include directories` or `additional include directories`.

**So the solution is that:**

Please remove the path of these header files under `include directories` and `additional include directories`.

[image]

**Then**, right-click on the **Header Files** folder of your c++ project-->**Add**-->**Existing Item** to add these header files into your project.

[image]

**Then**, you can see that Intellisense will recommend `""` rather than `<>`.

====================================================

**This is my test result:**

I have a header file called `header.h` and I configured its path into `additional include directories`, and when I call its variable, you can see:

[image]

[image]

If I removed the path from `additional include directories` and add it into the **Header Files** folder.

[image]

[image]